# How can I get logs in real time from a docker container hosted on Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, logging

I have a docker container in which I am running Flask and Scrapy.
I noticed that when I run and build my container on my local machine I get logs in real time. However, on an Ubuntu instance hosted on Digital Ocean, there are almost no updates to the logs.

I am using of course the same parameters for build and run.

Here is my config:

- local dev environement: OS Linux Mint, docker version 20.10.6
- cloud environment: OS Ubuntu 20, docker version 19.03.4

What can I do to update the frequency of the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the solution was related to python than to docker itself.
I had to use -U parameter when I run flask .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285782/what-do-u-m-parameters-do